# What is the proper procedure for spray painting metal and plastic?

Tags: paint

I've done a bit of studying around and I think I've grasped the basics, but if you could walk me through more nuances of spray painting, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Objective**: Spray paint on steel (and a little bit of plastic) for:

- semi-gloss finish
- high durability (chip, scratch, rust resistant)
- wet-cleanable (I think the semi-gloss coating should allow this)

**My current procedure**:

- Cover areas not to be painted with paper and tape.
- Scuff the surface down with 100-grit sandpaper. *[1]*
- Wipe clean.
- Prime. *[2]*
- Apply color coating. Let dry.
- Sand with 400-grit and apply another coat. 400-grit sand again. *[3]*
- ???
- Finished.

[1]: How do I know when I'm done with this pre-processing step? Do I have to scuff and remove the manufacturer's coat until I see the bare metal? Or do I just remove a significant part of it?
If you feel like you have time, can you name some reasons why I would want to do this? I imagine my primer/coating would stick better to metal than on top of another coating, but I'm not sure.

[2]: How much priming is enough? Should I be picky about primer choice?

[3]: I presume that this process gives the semi-glossy finish I want, but I don't see how multiple coat + fine sanding is going to achieve it. Will it really? Or do I finish with the color coating first, then apply a glossy enamel coat on top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did spraypaint a computer case a few years ago. It was glossy and I could see my reflection in it, but not as scratch-resistant as I hoped.

Question 1: You need to scuff to remove the smoothness of the steel and plastic to give the primer a surface to stick to. No need to go back to the bare metal.

Question 2: It depends how smooth you want your final result to be. Your end-result will be as good as your priming job. Prime, wet-sand with 1000grit paper, dry, repeat. I did this until I had removed all the "orange peel" feeling to my surface. (Took 6 or 7 coats) I used store-brand automotive primer and paint.

Question 3: This process give the smooth finish. The more coats/sanding you do, the smoother and glossier it will be. I used 1000grit for the first 3 coats, and then 2000grit for another 3 coats of paint.

The ??? step:

- Apply a few coats of clear coating. That's what I didn't do back then.
- When dry, polish it with car wax.